# Avoiding dependency collisions when replacing bower with npm

Tags: npm, bower

I feel I currently have package management nicely working for me when building web applications:  I keep all my server side dependencies in npm and all my client side dependencies in bower.

That said, I've been hearing talk about why it makes more sense to only use npm, especially since the release of v3. How do people keep their server side dependencies and client side dependencies from colliding when developing this way?

Comment: Why would they collide? Do you use different versions of libraries for your server side code than for your client side code?

Comment: Yes.  In large applications, its pretty common for me to want to bump the version of a library on the client without wanting to worry about breaking server side code...and vice-versa (granted this does not happen a lot...but it does happen).

Comment: Allright. Well, dependencies are stored hierarchically, so if a lib A depends on lib B, it'll be in `node_modules/A/node_modules/B`. Should be okay, but I haven't tried this (hence no answer). Alternatively, you could separate your client and server into two projects, each with their own package.json.